# Remove preview popup in Windows 7 using Classic theme

Tags: windows-7

This is what I want removed, anyone got a clue?

[image]

It's the actual popup I don't want, and I don't use grouping nor Aero theme.
I suspect this can't be done through regular settings but rather something like changing the time it takes for the popup to rise in the registry, or something alike.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Windows 7 taskbar thumbnails](https://superuser.com/questions/607759/remove-windows-7-taskbar-thumbnails)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the answer to your question. 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/496-taskbar-button-grouping-enable-disable.html

Answer (score 0):

This solved it.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

Set **ExtendedUIHoverTime** to 99999, then restart `explorer.exe`.